# Translate string in vuejs component in a .js file

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I installed this package to do my translations in my application laravel and vuejs : [laravel-vue-i18n-generator](https://github.com/martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator)

I generated my language file that looks like this

```
export default {
"en": {
    "API": "API",
    …
"fr": {
    "API": "Mon API"
 }
```

In my .Vue files, I can do this to translate my texts:

```
{ $t('message.API' }}
```

Only I use .js files for some of my components.

```
Vue.component('update-team-profile-details', {
  data() {
    return {
      …
  },

  mounted() {
    …
  },

  methods: {
    update() {
      Spark.put(this.urlForUpdate, this.form)
          .then(success => {
            // is success
            this.validateSuccess()
          }).catch(error => {
        // is error
        this.validateError();
      });
    },

    validateSuccess() {
      if (this.form.successful) {
        this.$message({
          message: $t('message.API),
          type: 'success'
        });
      }
    },

    validateError() {
      this.$message.error('Désolé… vos informations n’ont pas été sauvegardées. Veuillez corriger les erreurs et réessayer.');
    }
  }
  }
});
```

I'm trying to replace the message string with `$t('message.API)` but it doesn't work, do you have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: it seems `this.$t('message.API')`

Comment: You're not closing the string, and you're not referencing the Vue instance. It would probably need to be `this.$t('message.API')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sphinx and Thanksd said, I just forgot about this ... tsss